# Allocating memory for 64 8-byte blocks

Tags: c, memory

How do I allocate memory for 64 8-byte blocks?
I've tried reading on uint64, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Dynamic memory? It's usually not up to you to determine block size, but 64*8=512, so just `malloc(512)` or `malloc(64*8)` works fine too ofc, or a static array of `uint64_t array[64]`? And again, `what have you tried`?

Comment: That's fine in an alternate universe where 64 * 8 = 320. malloc (64 * 8) will work just fine.

Comment: `unsigned char (*blocks)[8] = malloc(64*sizeof(char[8]));`

Comment: @gnasher729 Lol, I'm tired and put my calculator in `hexadecimal`, fixed.

Comment: Will a static array of uint64_t array[64] grant me enough memory?
Also, will this memory dissappear, or will it stay continually through the program?

Comment: No love for `calloc()` here?

Comment: @Michael Burr How about `uint8_t (*Blocks)[8] = calloc(64, sizeof *Block);`?

Answer (score 1):

This should be very simple. Either run:

```
void *foo = malloc(64 * 8);
```

or, if you want type safety:

```
#if (CHAR_BIT != 8) #error Weird broken system, give up... #endif
uint64_t *foo = malloc(sizeof(uint64_t[64]));
```

Comment: The latter is not, IMO, "more nicely" at all.

Comment: @Jite It adds type safety no? That should be a big plus? However made it more specific

Comment: Type safety? It's a 64bit integer type, just as hardcoded as 8 is .. 8. But sure, if you feel you might mistype it, hope you don't slip and write uint32_t. If it would have been a variable you did sizeof on, I would agree.

Comment: But hey sure, there are some obscure systems where in fact 64bits != 8 bytes.

Comment: @Jite True, admittedly I am assuming POSIX compliance in that respect, in that the system will act as if a byte is an octet. I shall add an adaptation to this effect.

Comment: @Jite In addition this breaks all these answers as in that case malloc is in the unit if system bytes, not octets.

Answer (score 1):

In c, `malloc` allocates the number of bytes specified, so if you want to allocate 64 8 bytes blocks then you must allocate `malloc(64*8)`. Don't forget to `free` them.

If you are not going to allocate them dinamically you can just declare an array. In c there's a type that have 64 bits (8 bytes) named `uint64_t`, so you can declare an array of 64 elements of 8 bytes this way: `uint64_t blocks[64]`.

As a reply of a question in your comments, declaring a variable will make it valid inside his scope. So if you declare the array globally, it will be valid until the program closes. And if you declare it inside an `if` condition (for example), it will be valid only inside the conditional. Read this to understand better how it works: https://www.clear.rice.edu/elec201/ictutorial/tut2-4.html

If you allocate a piece of memory will `malloc`, it's direction must be saved in a variable so you can access it later, and here applies the same scope rules, but don't forget to `free` the memory before losing the direction pointer or you will have a memory leak.

If you don't have much experience I don't recommend using `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this just using `malloc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    void* ptr = malloc(sizeof(uint64_t) * 64);
    printf("Allocated memory begins at %p", ptr);
}
```

Comment: To `printf` a pointer, you should do `printf("%p", ptr)`, while making sure (as you do in this case) that `ptr` is a void pointer.

Comment: @BillLynch, thanks for information. Forgot about this specification.